# grounding predicates with python scripts in asp/clingo

Tags: python, scripting, clingo

I am using `clingo` version 4 and wish to be able to ground relations via python script (please don't ask why, it's not a crime, since you can at least ground 1-ary relations). I am hoping this is possible, and need some help.

```
#script (python)
import gringo;
def main(prg):
    prg.ground([('base', [])]);
    # ... compute somethings ...
    prg.ground([('myrel', [[10,20],[30,40],[70,40]])]);
    prg.solve();
#end.

#program myrel(x,y).
r(x,y).

#show r/2.
```

this doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this? I tried `[(10,20),(30,40),(70,40)]` instead, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but one has to input each entry one by one (which for my application is actually good). Instead of

```
prg.ground([('myrel', [[10,20],[30,40],[70,40]])]);
```

one has to write

```
prg.ground([('myrel', [10,20])]);
prg.ground([('myrel', [30,40])]);
prg.ground([('myrel', [70,40])]);
```

and then it is accepted and yields the right output.